# swapping between mobile view and desktop view on window resize

Tags: jquery, html

How can I swap desktop view and mobile view based on browser dimensions.
Like bostonglobe.com site it automatically swaps between mobile and desktop when i resize my window.
Is it HTML5 property or a jquery plugin ?

Comment: There are enormous questions like this one in SO, just search for it for 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awesome question.

There are a few resources I would like to send your way, for things like this I personally find it neat to try and piece it all together on your own.

First, read this thoroughly - [**Responsive Web Design**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)

get a firm grasp of media queries, what you can and can't do with them.

---

Other alternative resources - [**clever us of js event_listeners to detect browser window resolution changes**](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/ResolutionLayout/)

This is another alternative route, perhaps a little more work involved, but all the code is there.

---

[**lessframework**](http://lessframework.com/)

this is a css framework with a grid system designed with exactly what you are thinking in mind. not my favored approach, but the more options the better rite?

Good Luck..or er ahem, may your application of knowledge and determination bring you success, or something.